# SFTP code running on Azure occasional connection issues to server

Tags: c#, azure, sftp, ssh.net

https://sshnet.codeplex.com/discussions/462442

It's an old question I asked on the discussion forum. Unfortunately it's a problem that's come back to bite and I'm once again in need of a solution for it!

Essence is:

> I'm getting the below problem when deploying our app to our Azure production and UAT environments. Running this app locally causes no problems whatsoever. The application makes a number of attempts to connect to list directorys or download files into streams within a short space of time. However this exception is thrown in the test case after the first attempt to connect. However it should also be noted that this does not always happen, and soemtimes the client connects successfully.

```
var connInfo = new PasswordConnectionInfo(this.host, this.port, this.username, this.password);
        using (this.client = new SftpClient(connInfo))
        {
            client.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<Renci.SshNet.Common.ExceptionEventArgs>(client_ErrorOccurred);

            this.client.Connect();

            var response = new MemoryStream();
            this.client.DownloadFile(this.intraDayFilePath, response);


            this.client.Disconnect();
        }
```

And the exception:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:22



 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.SocketConnect(String host, Int32 port)
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.Connect()
   at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.Connect()
   at ---------
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```